# 405 Method not Allowed/CORS origin problem when redirecting to Angular application in IdentityServer4 login

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an Angular App as an Login UI (rendered in Backend (Asp Net Core)). When we try to login it goes to login method and validate the username/password. Our doubt is about what we should do to IndentityServer correctly redirect to redirectUrl (client to be logged) with cookies **return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);**.

[Login method with Redirect Uri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUUdl.png)

[CORS/405 error in chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp4U6.png)

It looks like some problem with routes/cors but I can't figure it out.

Edit 1:

Code in github with the problem:

https://github.com/kewinbrand/so-405-idsvr-angular

in README.md are the steps to run

Comment: Can you update your question to include the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: do you have a CORS policy in place? If not, enable it, and allow a list of known hosts such as that 192 url, try it out with wildcard * first.  Your CORS error is because your redirecting to another resource that isn't trusted, which is exactly what CORS is supposed to do.

Comment: @quicklikerabbit I uploaded an entire project showing the problem.

Comment: @RandomUs1r in my example any origin is allowed

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what I should type instead of just receiving down votes.

Comment: I would guess the question is receiving down votes because there's no code in the actual question. Anyone who wants to help will have to go to at least 3 links before they can even understand what the issue is. Perhaps you can edit your question to include some of this code you've linked to?

Comment: does the other resource have allow origin = * too?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow allowedCrosorigion inside client configuration like below.

[image: Try above clinet configuration]